# Allow anyone to view future posts of a certain post type (events) in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, permissions

I have had a system on Wordpress where events are scheduled posts and word great in loops.

However I just noticed that when clicking on an event and going to it's page, it gives a 404. I can preview it when I'm logged in, however, I need to it to be visible by anyone even though it's currently scheduled.

Is there a way to change permissions so that anyone can view a specific scheduled post type?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Future posts are a bit of a Catch-22: You can query them in any good old-fashioned Wordpress Loop, but navigating to them directly *is not possible*..... at least, within the standard Wordpress Scope:

```
<?php
$q = new WP_Query(array('post_status'=>'future'));
if($q->have_posts()) : while($q->have_posts()) : $q->the_post;
    echo '<a href="'.get_permalink().'">'.get_the_title().'</a>'; //404 when clicked
endwhile;endif;
?>
```

The reason for this is not because of permissions. It's because that's how it's built in the Wordpress Core. Future Posts are not intended to be viewable until a specific date. Trying to make future posts available for viewing is a misuse of the 'future' status and defeats its whole purpose which is to schedule a post or a page to automatically switch to a status of 'Published' when the designated date has been reached.

If, however, you still want to make Future Posts available as if they're normal posts, [This discussion](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/display-future-posts-solutions) can probably shed some light on various methods and plugins to make everything happen the way you want.

Good luck.

Answer (score 3):

Edited:

Try adding this function to your functions.php file:

```
/* Show future posts */
function show_future_posts($posts)
{
   global $wp_query, $wpdb;
   if(is_single() && $wp_query->post_count == 0)
   {
      $posts = $wpdb->get_results($wp_query->request);
   }
   return $posts;
}
add_filter('the_posts', 'show_future_posts');
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried several plugins and suggestions for this problem, but none worked to show a single custom post type template page to non-logged in users. Eventually I found my answer:

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/44202/how-to-set-a-custom-post-type-to-have-viewable-future-posts/70155#70155