# access to upcoming post even if user isn't logged in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have upcoming posts which are scheduled and will be published later. But I want to see its single page even if I'm not logged in wordpress.

When I'm logged in, I see it. But when I'm logging out, it goes to error 404 page. How can I make it accessible in both cases (logged in and logged out) ?

Comment: Hi aida, I don't think what you plan to do is usefull - if you want it to be visible don't hide it by a timestamp. Please provide clearer information why you need it. Should only YOU be able to access it or EVERYONE?

Comment: I want upcoming post to be accessible for everyone ? @ThomasB

Comment: @ThomasB - Upcoming courses are upcoming because they will be held in the future which means the course will be upcoming but the page will be live. I just want to see them even if they aren't published yet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found answer to my question, all I wanted is to have upcoming posts which will be available to users even if they aren't published yet. Solution is taken from [**HERE**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12572703/allow-anyone-to-view-future-posts-of-a-certain-post-type-events-in-wordpress/12574440#answer-12574440).

Just pasted below code in my functions.php file and it is working:

```
function show_future_posts($posts){
   global $wp_query, $wpdb;
   if(is_single() && $wp_query->post_count == 0)
   {
      $posts = $wpdb->get_results($wp_query->request);
   }
   return $posts;
}
add_filter('the_posts', 'show_future_posts');
```